# Remove from select only entries which repeat a certain value

Tags: mysql

So, i have a very complicated database structure which I hope I won't have to detail. The main idea is that we have, lets say

```
Name WasHeHere

Robert yes
Michael yes
Robert no
Michael yes
John no
Robert yes
```

What I need is: primarily to sort a select (with multiple inner joins) after a certain value `('yes')` of field A `(WasHeHere)` and then (and only then) remove any other rows which repeat a name.

*The result should be:*

```
Name WasHeHere

Robert yes
Michael yes
John no
```

Is there a MySql query that can do that?

And yes, I want to filter a select (JDeveloper, don't know why I cannot submit my answer to your question)

Comment: Do you need to filter a select query ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` for filtering unique record.

You can try this :-

```
select distinct(Name),WasHeHere,case WasHeHere when 'yes' then '1' else '0' end as pstatus from tablename order by pstatus desc;
```

[Read more.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Tried it, does not help. I make an 'order by' after the 'select' (The 'order by' is made after the 'select) Thus, at the time of the order, the selected values are already those with unique values. And I need to have the name with the 'yes' value first, if there is one.

Comment: Then you need to create a new status column(pstatus) using select join query , suppose 'yes' the value will be 1 and 'no' the value will be 0.Then sort order by pstatus desc(i.e it will show only Yes data first).

Comment: Isn't it the same thing if i directly order by WasHeHere asc? What I need to do afterwards is to remove the names which already had a yes.